# Scraping Web Table with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Running Powershell, my code has stopped working when extracting all elements. Previously It was able to run and extract the information for passing on to exportation via CSV. Now it will hang when I run AllElements

```
#Open website
$webSite = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://www.oreas.com/crm/OREAS-606 -Method Get

#Find table in the website
$tableHeader = $webSite.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagname -eq 'th'}
$tableData = $webSite.AllElements | Where-Object {$_.tagname -eq 'td'}

#Table header and data
$thead = $tableHeader.innertext[0..5]
$tdata = $tableData.innertext
```